# Converting scripts from ksh to bash

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

I have some ksh scripts which I'd like to convert to run with bash instead.

Are there any useful on-line resources for this?

I'm really looking for a list of differences between the two shells and any gotchas I might encounter, although all information is welcome :-)

Comment: Have you tried running a ksh script in bash? What happened?

Comment: This line:

while [ i -lt ${#1} ]

caused this message:

[: i: integer expression expected

Jan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [this](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/shell-differences/) page? It has a useful matrix of features and links to elsewhere.

Also [this](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/bash/) link, search for:

> C2)  How does bash differ from the Korn shell

Answer (score 2):

Here's a comparison from CMU on the differences between shells:

- http://linuxclass.heinz.cmu.edu/misc/shell-comparison.htm

Here's a great set of UNIX shell tutorials from Richard's Shell Scripting Universe:

- https://accounts.smccd.edu/sinkewitsch/msink/shell/page201.htm

The second is by far one of the most useful scripting resources I have found, and it really helps you learn how to write scripts with portability in mind.

Good luck with your conversions.

**2024 EDIT**: Updating links to active sites instead of linking through the wayback machine.

Comment: The hp link is no longer valid.

Comment: The link to Richard's Shell Scripting Universe is also broken now.